# Ruby if, elsif, and else conditional statement error with no output

Tags: ruby

Here is my Ruby code. When I execute it, it asks the question, then when I put no or yes, nothing happens. It just ends.

```
puts "Do you like cats (Yes or No)?"
ans = gets.chomp

def answer(ans)
  if ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes"
    returns "Ken does too"
  elsif ans == "No" || ans == "no"
    returns "Dogs are better"
  else 
    returns "It's hard to decide"
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how this question is off topic or unclear.  The poster just needs some help getting started with Ruby.  We need to ensure the poster gets good information on how to get started instead of discouragment!

Comment: I agrée and that's why I +1 his question. Keep on learning, it will click.

Comment: Voting to close since the topic is basic knowledge covered by any tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few corrections:

1. You are not calling the method `answer` at all.
2. Make sure you define the method before calling it.
3. The keyword `returns` is undefined, it's supposed to be `return`.
4. Make sure to call the method you intend to use.

Try as follows and follow a good Ruby book.  Here might be a good start: https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md

```
def answer(ans)
  if ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes"
    return "Ken does too"
  elsif ans == "No" || ans == "no"
    return "Dogs are better"
  else 
    return "It's hard to decide"
  end
end

puts "Do you like cats (Yes or No)?"
ans = gets.chomp

puts answer(ans)
```

Comment: @user2066488, very nice.  Enjoy Ruby.

Comment: Nicely broken down @vee

Answer (score 1):

You did not call your `answer()` method anywhere. Also, `returns` is incorrect (`return` is). In Ruby, we try to avoid explicit return. You want to print the string output using `puts`:

```
 puts "Do you like cats (Yes or No)?"
    ans = gets.chomp

    def answer(ans)
      if ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes"
          puts"Ken does too"
      elsif ans == "No" || ans == "no"
          puts"Dogs are better"
      else
          puts"It's hard to decide"
      end
    end

    answer(ans)
```

Comment: I would recommend actually using `print` instead of `puts` inside of your control statement as `puts` creates an extra line with the output.

Comment: Right that's also a solution. What about just putting the string literally without any puts or print

Comment: That is a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `print` in your control statement will avoid adding an extra line to your output.

[Difference Between print and puts in ruby](https://matt.berther.io/2009/02/11/puts-vs-print-in-ruby/)

`def answer(ans)
  if ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes"
    print "Ken does too"
  elsif ans == "No" || ans == "no"
    print "Dogs are better"
  else 
    print "It's hard to decide"
  end
end`

`puts "Do you like cats (Yes or No)?"
ans = gets.chomp`

`puts answer(ans)`

Answer (score -1):

Use `return` instead of `returns`, or better the "ruby-way" would be this:

```
puts "Do you like cats (Yes or No)?"
ans = gets.chomp

def answer(ans)
  if ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes"
    "Ken does too"
  elsif ans == "No" || ans == "no"
    "Dogs are better"
  else 
    "It's hard to decide"
  end
end

puts answer(ans)
```

Comment: That will not print any string to the console since you are not calling the method `answer(ans)`

Comment: Based on his code, check last line of his code: puts answer(ans) / edit, oh lol sorry, it is in code from answer :/

Comment: No that's not correct, your code will not output the answer because you are not calling the method anywhere. Take a look at @vee's answer or mine...That'll help